# Selecting directory's path with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, tkinter

I'm trying to get the full path of a directory using Tkinter, but only the directory name is being displayed.

For example when I select "C:\Python27\Doc", instead of the full path being displayed, only "Doc" displays.

```
class Actions:

    def openfile(self): #open the file  
        directory = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
        print(directory)


    def body(self):
        Label (text='Please select a directory').pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)
```

I found this http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog , but unless I'm misunderstanding it, I don't see anything for the full path.

Comment: I can't duplicate your results. Are you using python 2.7? What platform? Maybe this is a platform-specific issue. When I use `tkFileDialog.askdirectory()` on Windows I always get a fully qualified path.

Comment: When you say you get only "Doc", what is your current working directory? Is it the parent of "Doc"? If so, what if you pick a directory that is not a child of your current working directory?

Comment: I'm using 2.7 on windows. mgilson's answer shows the full path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the initialdir keyword? e.g. `tkFileDialog.askdirectory(initialdir='.')`. What do you get then?

Comment: Small addendum: `tkFileDialog` is renamed to `tkinter.filedialog` in Python 3.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker -- Thanks for that update.  I assume that 2to3 would take care of that.

Comment: Yeah, it probably does. But I like to write my code so that it works on *both* python 2 & 3, since 2.7 is still the default on many systems (AFAIK only ArchLinux uses 3 by default)